# reader writer problem in operating system

Tags: operating-system

In Reader-writer problem, if a Writer is writing some data, can other reader reads the data at the same time?

If no, this is the code present in Operating system-Galvin how does it taking care of above situation

Writer's process:

```
do {
    wait(rw mutex);
    . . ./* writing is performed */
    signal(rw mutex);
} while (true);
```

Reader's process:

```
do {
    wait(mutex);
    read count++;
    if (read count == 1)
        wait(rw mutex);
    signal(mutex);
    . . ./* reading is performed */
    wait(mutex);
    read count--;
    if (read count == 0)
        signal(rw mutex);
    signal(mutex);
} while (true);
```

Comment: Yet another person confused by this book. Generally it is possible to have multiple readers and a single writer. It depends on how the object is locked. A writer can take out an an exclusive lock and block readers or it can take out a write lock and allow readers.

Answer (score 1):

- As seen above in the code for the writer, the writer just waits on
  the rw mutex semaphore until it gets a chance to write to the
  resource.
- After performing the write operation, it increments w so    that the
  next writer can access the resource.
- On the other hand, in    the code for the reader, the lock is
  acquired whenever the read_count    is updated by a process.
- When a reader wants to access the resource,    first it increments
  the read_count value, then accesses the resource    and then
  decrements the read_count value.
- The semaphore rw mutex is    used by the first reader which enters
  the critical section and the    last reader which exits the critical
  section.
- The reason for this is,    when the first readers enters the critical
  section, the writer is    blocked from the resource.
- Only new readers can access the resource    now.
- Similarly, when the last reader exits the critical section, it
  signals the writer using the rw mutex semaphore because there are
  zero readers now and a writer can have the chance to access the
  resource.

Comment: Hope This helps you..!